# Search a log file for a value until it changes, then group and count the values

Tags: python

I have some log files (like below) and like to search them through a Python script.

The script searches for the value `Plugged=1` till it changes.
Between the lines there is al kin of other info which i sniped out of it.
If that appears i like to print the time between the changes.
So for example with this log file, I’d like that the message is something like

```
2018-08-16 00:05:17.96 till 2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 = plugged=1 and has 4 lines

2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 till 2018-08-16 00:07:56.961 = plugged=0 and has 2 lines
```

```
2018-08-16 00:05:17.962 level=42, plugged=1}
2018-08-16 00:05:48.950 level=43, plugged=1}
2018-08-16 00:06:35.942 level=44, plugged=1}
2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 level=45, plugged=1}
-----
2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 level=45, plugged=0}
2018-08-16 00:07:56.961 level=46, plugged=0}
```

Comment: Ok, so from what I understand, you have a log file. in which variables are stored with their values in the format `(var=value)` and you wish to detect changes in var between scans? Do you only need scan for change in one variable or all of them? i.e. You only wish to detect if plugged has changed or also other variables, also will your code run the whole time or do you need it to save its state from previous time the code ran?

Comment: The only value which is imported is the "plugged=" value, so that the thing i want to detect. its not a "live" log so the code needs to run one time over the log file and print the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a key function that extracts the `plugged=` portion of the input as the key:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter
print('\n'.join('{2} till {3} = plugged={0} and has {1} lines'.format(k[0], len(l), *(' '.join(s.split()[:2]) for s in itemgetter(0, -1)(l))) for k, g in groupby(filter(lambda l: 'plugged=' in l, f), key=partial(re.findall, r'\bplugged=(\d+)')) if k for l in (list(g),)))
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
2018-08-16 00:05:17.962 till 2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 = plugged=1 and has 4 lines
2018-08-16 00:07:25.949 till 2018-08-16 00:07:56.961 = plugged=0 and has 2 lines
```

Comment: Tnx so far! i get the following error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I've updated the answer that the code now ignores lines that do not match the pattern.

Comment: Its almost working, in the whole log it displays the following, but its not grouped right, any idea?

Comment: As I commented in your "answer", the reason it's not grouped right is because you have non-matching lines in between lines that are supposed to be in the same group. I've updated my code accordingly. Please give it another try.

Comment: is there a way to get the data out of your code with to put it in a panadas dataframe?.
So for example that with "result[2] = 2018-08-16 00:00:38.439" and "result[0] = 1" etc?